# Always play sound when new e-mail message received

Tags: thunderbird

How to make Thunderbird to play a sound on each new e-mail message, even if there are unread messages?
By default it plays only on the first message and if I don't read it, then it ignores all newer messages.

I tried to create filter that reads all messages but then it does not play at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using [FiltaQuilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/filtaquilla/) extension (filter action to launch file/application) + simple application to play sound.